# get max count distinct

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I want to get a max count from database using `knex.js`

```
bookshelf.knex('user').distinct('social_name')
        .select('social_image_url')
        .count('status as score').innerJoin('game', function(){
            this.on('game.user_id', 'user.id');
        }).innerJoin('round', function(){
            this.on('round.game_id', 'game.id');
        }).where('status', 'win')
        .groupBy('game.id', 'user.id')
        .orderBy('score', 'desc')
        .limit(10)
        .then(function(top10){
            callback(null, top10);
        }).catch(function(err){
            callback(err);
        });
```

but this is what i get

```
[ { social_name: 'B', social_image_url: '.....', score: 4 },
  { social_name: 'A', social_image_url: '.....', score: 3 },
  { social_name: 'A', social_image_url: '.....', score: 2 } ]
```

I got two records of `social_name: A` rather than getting it only max of it which is

```
{ social_name: 'A', social_image_url: '.....', score: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this by creating sub-query first and then use that inner join with it.